# How to save users post in the database in laravel?

Tags: database, laravel, eloquent, model, controller

I am very new to Laravel and working on a project. I have a user table,category table(category_id,category_name) and pets table(id,user_id,category_id,breed,description....).How can i make the user add post and make his id and cagtegory_id that he had chosen from select option save in user_id and category_id in pets table ??

Comment: can you post your html and controller, it is very simple but I wanna see how you try first

Comment: is the user is authenticated or normal user (login user or just a user)

Comment: I am searching for a lot of tutorial and am not able to figure anything.this one is my Controller Page
class RehomeController extends Controller
{
    public function rehome(Request $show){

            $breed = $show->input('breed');
            $gender = $show->input('gender');
            $age = $show->input('age');
            $color = $show ->color;
            $height = $show ->height;
            $description = $show ->description;
            $health = $show ->health;

            return view('posts.blade')->with('breed',$breed);

    }
}

Comment: It is login user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let assume your form have category_id, name, etc,.

Try like below code

```
$pet = new PET_MODEL_NAME;
$pet->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
$pet->category_id = $request->category_id;
$pet->name = $request->name;
$pet->save();
return back()->withSuccess('Pet added success!');
```

Explanation

1. `$pet` will call your `petModel` where you want to save the data;
2. `$pet->user_id` is `user_id` in your database;
3. `Auth::user()->id` is current login user_id and so on
4. $pet->something (before `=`) indicated column in database and (after `=`) indicate the data from `form` submitted

Comment: For category, I had already saved the data through the database.My form contains field like category,breed,age,height and others and I had retrieved the data from the database for the category.

Comment: I'm talking about your pet table only.. that category you have saved have to used in this `pet` table

Comment: can you post your html (your form)

Comment: The code is too long.I will post it by parting them.

Comment: To add image do i follow the same process or i need to code more that the following code above?

Answer (score 0):

In your HTML:

```
<form action="/pet-url" method="post">
    @csrf
    <input type="text" name="pet_name">
    <select name="category_id" id="">
        <option value="1">Category 1</option>
        <option value="2">Category 2</option>
        <option value="3">Category 3</option>
    </select>
</form>
```

In your route:

```
Route::post('/pet-url', 'PetController@store');
```

In your controller:

```
public function store(Request $request) {
    $pet = new Pet;
    $pet->user_id = Auth::user()->id;
    $pet->category_id = $request->category_id;
    $pet->name = $request->pet_name;
    $pet->save();
    return back()->withSuccess('Pet added success!');
}
```

Comment: I am getting an error "Class 'App\Http\Controllers\Pet' not found"

Comment: `use App\Pet` I assumed that `Pet` is your model. if not then changed to your model name